# $\pi_{1}(X)$ abelian criteria

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification

$X$ is a path-connected topological space.
Let $\beta_{h}$ be homomorphism $\pi_{1}(X,x_0) \to \pi_{1}(X, x_1), [f] \mapsto [h  f h^{-1}]$($h$ is a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$).
I want to prove that $\pi_{1}(X)$ is abelian $\iff$ $\beta_h$ depends only on $x_0, x_1$.

I say that $\pi_{1}(X)$ is abelian $\iff \beta_{h}(fg) = \beta_h(gf)$.
But $hf \simeq hg, gh^{-1} \simeq fh^{-1}$, so $hfgh^{-1} \simeq hgfh^{-1}$.
Is this proof correct?

Comment: Consider two  paths $h_1$, $h_2$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$. What can you conclude from $\beta_{h_1}(f) = \beta_{h_2}(f)$ ? A picture might help.

Comment: I cant conclude anything except $h_1 f h_{1}^{-1} \simeq h_2 f h_{2}^{-1}$ ;(
And what's wrong in my proof?

Comment: Now you get $(h_2^{-1}h_1 )\,f \simeq f\, (h_2^{-1} h_1)$, and this equality is in $\pi_1(X, x_0)$.

Comment: Yeah, your proof should use two different path but with same start and end points, and probe what it means that they give the same map. So $\beta_h$ should only depend on $x_0$ and $x_1$ and not on the actual $\beta $ that joins them.

Comment: I should use that for any path $g$ there $h_1, h_1$ such $g \simeq h_{2}^{-1}h_1$?
Thx!

Comment: Yes, take a loop based at $x_0$, you can deform it to pass through $x_1$ (  take  any point on the curve and add a filament going to $x_1$ and back ) and then it is a composition $h_2^{-1} h_1$. Excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to first look at the case where you have $x_0=x_1$. Then $\beta_h$ will be just conjugation by an element $[h] \in \pi_1(X)$, right? Now if you can choose any $h$ and you will get the same homomorphism, in particular $\beta_h = id$, you get that $\forall x,y \in \pi_1(X): yxy^{-1} =x$ i.e. $xy=yx$. On the other hand, conjugation on an abelian group, gives you always the identity, which means in our case $\beta_h$ does not depend on $h$.

You are welcome to generalize it to $x_0\neq x_1$! (Use the fact proven above!)